# Base way to handle multiple http calls simultaneously in android

Tags: android, httpwebrequest, httprequest, androidhttpclient

I am creating a social app. In this there are many http calls. I have create a method  to handle which is used for http calls. I have created saprate AsyncTask for each request. My problem is the responce is very slow if there is multiple http requests send simultaneously.
Please tell me how to resolve this problem (what is the best way to handle multiple Http request at same time).

Comment: Have you checked if slow network connection is the reason? In that case, I think there is not much to do.

Comment: thanks for your reply. The network connection is fine. I need to, is there any way to speed up the response in case of multiple request at the same time...

Comment: You should be looking server-side as well, are you sure that the server is able to gracefully handle multiple requests?